# Login with Twitter using passport.js in node.js not working

Tags: node.js, twitter, passport.js, twitter-oauth, passport-twitter

I am using passport.js for twitter login in node.js. But it is not working. It is stay in process for sometime, then return without error or success.

My Code:

```
module.exports.loginWithTwitter = function (req, res) {

var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('strategy');
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: "HMtGdCax3EMhUAikCi2uySwoQ",
    consumerSecret: "QZlWEdjVbPkWPr7cfS6ohbZgNAkpiboRbP0HGaiv1AvTJRtATw",
    callbackURL: "http://192.168.0.102:4000/api/userData/get"
}, function (token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) {
    console.log('call');
    process.nextTick(function () {
        console.log(profile);
    });
}));
}
```

I am not getting "console.log('call');" call.

My App.js Code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    http = require('http'),
    cors = require('cors');


app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var allowedorigins = ['http://localhost:4000'];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;
    //if (allowedorigins.indexof(origin) > -1) {
    //    res.setheader('access-control-allow-origin', origin);
    //}
    res.header("access-control-allow-credentials", "true");
    res.header("access-control-allow-headers", "x-requested-with");
    res.header("access-control-allow-headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept,application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json,application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        Server: "A"
    }));
});

var passport = require('passport');
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res) {
    console.log('callback')
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Eviral'); // mongo DB Connection

var server = app.listen(4000);
var router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '100mb',
    extended: true
})); // configure app to use bodyParser() this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '100mb'
}));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var _send = res.send;
    var sent = false;
    res.send = function(data) {
        if (sent) return;
        _send.bind(res)(data);
        sent = true;
    };
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(require('./routes/clientMSTRoute'));
```

Comment: If there are any other plugin for twitter oauth for NodeJS, it is welcome.

Comment: I think you have defined strategy correctly, but how are you going to attach it to `node.js` app. Try this example https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-twitter-example/blob/master/server.js

Comment: @MukeshSharma Still i fetch same issue. I am testing in localhost, is this problem for localhost??

Comment: Can you show your `app.js` code? How you are initilaizing passport, Also if you can show how you are calling the authentication strategy from your routes.

Comment: @RaviShankar I Update App.js file code. PLZ review

Comment: where are you returning the `User`? what is your `process.nextTick()` doing?

Comment: I need to reach at "console.log('call');" this point.

Comment: is that all your `app.js` code? Are you not using express-sessions, `body-parser` `cookie-parser`? Cause you need to do that to make sure your json object in your request, and response body gets parsed.

Comment: @RaviShankar I Update App.js file code. PLZ review

Comment: i have added answer, but i wrote that before your update, if you dont understand it, tell me. i will update it.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue not able to reach that console.log('call')

Comment: i'm struggling with this same issue, did anyone ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized passport in your `app.js`. You need to `configure` `passport`, before using its `authentication strategies`.

Also, you need to `initialize express-session` to create login sessions for you users.

Add these lines in your `app.js`. Ingore whatever you already have some of them. But, make sure you maintain the order.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your_secret_keyword' }));
//Below two lines are required to initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());//this should come after express-session  
                            //to ensure login session is restored in correct order
```

Make sure you import all the required `node modules`. Below are the one's required for these. Add those you dont already have in your `app.js`

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
```

Please read [passport configure documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) for more information.